# RewriteCond for .htaccess explanation

Tags: .htaccess

i am learning htaccess and have come across these lines, im am not sure what they do.

can some one please help me to explain what these conditions do

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.feed|\.pdf|\.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of these conditions attempts to match a regular expression against the request URI. So you need to look at what the 2 regex patterns match against.

```
(/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.feed|\.pdf|\.raw|/[^.]*)$
```

This can be anything that ends with a `/`, or the following extensions: `php`, `html`, `htm`, `feed`, `pdf`, or `raw`. Or, it can end with anything that doesn't have an extension. The `$` indicates the "end" of the string.

The second one is just that the URI doesn't start with `/index.php`.

```
!^/index.php
```

The `^` is the "beginning" of the string, and the `!` means that it doesn't match. So it's simply the URI doesn't match `^/index.php`.